# Sencha, AMFPHP and RESTfull services

Tags: rest, sencha-touch, extjs, amfphp

I'm working with models in Sencha. The data comes from an AMFPHP-service. I read in the docs that when you use the .save()-method, Sencha makes a POST-request to the URL you have given.

How is it possible to handle those requests in AMFPHP? Doe I have to make different functions, or switch-case something?

Hope someone can help me with this! Other suggestions are also good, just like to know how to work with models and save data with them in combination with AMFPHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case. I have a flex project that uses amfphp to communicate with a data service, and am currently developing a second project with Ext JS that needs the same data.

My solution is to write my own gateway in the front end and bypass the ext proxies...

I'm curious how others have handled this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for commenting! Can you let me / us know how you will handle the gateway?

Comment: On the javascript side, I am creating a new Ext.Ajax.request, passing in a callback function on success to handle the response.  On the php side, I'm using a version of AMFPHP's json gateway, slightly modified to also handle post vars.